# How can I replace one Youtube URL pattern with another via FoxReplace?

Tags: firefox, regex, firefox-extensions, youtube

Youtube changed its layout again. Now to get to a user’s uploads page you have to click on their nickname, then on the “Videos” tab, and *then* filter by uploads-only from a dropdwon menu. If you also want the uploads to be sorted by views, that adds one more point-and-click to make for each time.

Currently, the 1st link to the channel page from a video has the following structure:

```
https://www.youtube.com/user/[NICKNAME]?feature=watch (1)
```

and the wanted final link to the properly sorted uploads video page has the following structure:

```
https://www.youtube.com/user/[NICKNAME]/videos?sort=p&view=0&flow=grid (2)
```

**Question:** How can I make [FoxReplace](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxreplace/) convert all the hyperlinks of the first kind within the www.youtube.com* domain into the second kind?

*(A greasemonkey script could’ve been another solution, but currently there aren’t any fitting scripts at userscripts.org.)*

Answer (score 0):

To be replaced: (a selector I guess)
    https?://www.youtube.com/user/(.+)\?feature=watch

Replacement:
    https://www.youtube.com/user/\0/videos\?sort=p&view=0&flow=grid

Note: I don't use the extension, so I can't test. Just remove the domain part if it doesn't need it. This is a regex expression, they're pretty useful. The extension has a regex mode according to the link.